# Create a custom config xml [HELP]

Tags: magento-2.1, configuration, custom

I want to create a simple configuration. But I can't get the data attributes (countryCode and class) from it. Can you help me please ?

assignment_adapter.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:MyVendor_CommercialAssign:etc/assignment_adapter.xsd">
    <map countryCode="Default" class="Default"/>
    <map countryCode="FR" class="FR"/>
</config>
```

assignment_adapter.xsd :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="config">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="map" type="mapType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="mapType">
        <xs:attribute name="countryCode" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="class" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

di.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="AssignmentAdapterReader" type="Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="converter" xsi:type="object">MyVendor\CommercialAssign\Model\Config\Assignment\Converter</argument>
            <argument name="schemaLocator" xsi:type="object">MyVendor\CommercialAssign\Model\Config\Assignment\SchemaLocator</argument>
            <argument name="fileName" xsi:type="string">assignment_adapter.xml</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="MyVendor\CommercialAssign\Model\Config\Assignment\Data">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="reader" xsi:type="object">AssignmentAdapterReader</argument>
            <argument name="cacheId" xsi:type="string">myvendor_commercial_assignement_map_cache</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Here is my converter convert function :

```
public function convert($source)
    {
        $maps = $source->getElementsByTagName('map');
        $mapInfo = [];

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($maps as $map) {
            $mapInfo[$i]['complete'] = $map;
            $mapInfo[$i]['attributes'] = $map->attributes;
            $mapInfo[$i]['child'] = $map->childNodes;
            $i++;
        }

        return ['map' => $mapInfo];
    }
```

My Data class content :

```
use \Magento\Framework\Config\Data as DataConfig;

class Data extends DataConfig
{
}
```

So when I did a get('map') from my data reader I get this (there is no countryCode or class from the xml why ?) :

```
array(2) {
  [0] => array(3) {
    ["complete"] => object(DOMElement)#148 (18) {
      ["tagName"] => string(3) "map"
      ["schemaTypeInfo"] => NULL
      ["nodeName"] => string(3) "map"
      ["nodeValue"] => string(0) ""
      ["nodeType"] => int(1)
      ["parentNode"] => string(22) "(object value omitted)"
      ["childNodes"] => string(22) "(object value omitted)"
      ["firstChild"] => NULL
      ["lastChild"] => NULL
      ["previousSibling"] => string(22) "(object value omitted)"
      ["nextSibling"] => string(22) "(object value omitted)"
      ["attributes"] => string(22) "(object value omitted)"
      ["ownerDocument"] => string(22) "(object value omitted)"
      ["namespaceURI"] => NULL
      ["prefix"] => string(0) ""
      ["localName"] => string(3) "map"
      ["baseURI"] => string(36) "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/"
      ["textContent"] => string(0) ""
    }
    ["attributes"] => object(DOMNamedNodeMap)#140 (1) {
      ["length"] => int(2)
    }
    ["child"] => object(DOMNodeList)#134 (1) {
      ["length"] => int(0)
    }
  }
  [1] => array(3) {
    ["complete"] => object(DOMElement)#123 (18) {
      ["tagName"] => string(3) "map"
      ["schemaTypeInfo"] => NULL
      ["nodeName"] => string(3) "map"
      ["nodeValue"] => string(0) ""
      ["nodeType"] => int(1)
      ["parentNode"] => string(22) "(object value omitted)"
      ["childNodes"] => string(22) "(object value omitted)"
      ["firstChild"] => NULL
      ["lastChild"] => NULL
      ["previousSibling"] => string(22) "(object value omitted)"
      ["nextSibling"] => string(22) "(object value omitted)"
      ["attributes"] => string(22) "(object value omitted)"
      ["ownerDocument"] => string(22) "(object value omitted)"
      ["namespaceURI"] => NULL
      ["prefix"] => string(0) ""
      ["localName"] => string(3) "map"
      ["baseURI"] => string(36) "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/"
      ["textContent"] => string(0) ""
    }
    ["attributes"] => object(DOMNamedNodeMap)#135 (1) {
      ["length"] => int(2)
    }
    ["child"] => object(DOMNodeList)#146 (1) {
      ["length"] => int(0)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the outputed section each element has two attributes but you just need to read them.

```
["attributes"] => object(DOMNamedNodeMap)#140 (1) {
  ["length"] => int(2)
}
```

Try using the [getAttribute](http://php.net/manual/de/domelement.getattribute.php) method to do this.

```
public function convert($source)
{
    $maps = $source->getElementsByTagName('map');
    $mapInfo = [];

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($maps as $map) {
        $mapInfo[$i]['complete'] = $map;
        $mapInfo[$i]['countryCode'] = $map->getAttribute('countryCode');
        $mapInfo[$i]['class'] = $map->getAttribute('class');
        $mapInfo[$i]['child'] = $map->childNodes;
        $i++;
    }

    return ['map' => $mapInfo];
}
```

Or you could loop through the attributes to get the information.

```
foreach ($map->attributes as $attrName => $attrNode) {
```

Comment: Thanks, It works well. I searched for the class DOMNamedNodeMap but I don't know why my IDE won't find it :/